# How to get all the values in a select list with a AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectlist

I'm passing the selected values of my dropdown list with the following code:

```
function getData(){
       //Variabelen die worden gehaald uit de gekozen dropdown selecties
        $('#slctTable, #slctField, #slctAttribute').change(function ()
        {
            //var fieldvalues = fieldValues; 
            var tableSelected = document.getElementById("slctTable").value;
            var fieldSelected = document.getElementById("slctField").value;
            var attributeSelected = document.getElementById("slctAttribute").value;
            $.ajax({
                "url": "php/getData.php",
                "type": "GET",
                "data": {
                    //fieldValues: fieldValues, 
                    tableSelected: tableSelected,
                    fieldSelected: fieldSelected,
                    attributeSelected: attributeSelected
                },
                success: function(data){
                   // mapData(data);
                }
            })
        });
    };
```

But now I want to get al the values of the select lists and pass them in the variables: tableList, fieldList and attributeList. Can i do that the same way as I did with the selected values?

Comment: If you are using jQuery why are you using `document.getElementById`? Switch it to `$("#someId")`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event bindings in a function call is not a good way to bind an event, it can lead to multiple bindings. ***Better to do this in the doc ready block***.

> *But now I want to get al the values of the select lists and pass them in the variables: tableList, fieldList and attributeList. Can i do that the same way as I did with the selected values?*

```js
function allValues(el) {
  var arr = $('option', el).map(function(i, v) {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  return arr;
}
$('#slctTable, #slctField, #slctAttribute').change(function() {
  //var fieldvalues = fieldValues; 
  var tableSelected = document.getElementById("slctTable").value;
  var fieldSelected = document.getElementById("slctField").value;
  var attributeSelected = document.getElementById("slctAttribute").value;
  var tableList = allValues($('#slctTable'));
  var fieldList = allValues($('#slctField'));
  var attributeList = allValues($('#slctAttribute'));
  $.ajax({
    "url": "php/getData.php",
    "type": "GET",
    "data": {
      //fieldValues: fieldValues, 
      tableSelected: tableSelected,
      fieldSelected: fieldSelected,
      attributeSelected: attributeSelected,
      tableList: tableList,
      fieldList: fieldList,
      attributeList: attributeList
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // mapData(data);
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function getData() {
        //Variabelen die worden gehaald uit de gekozen dropdown selecties
        $('#slctTable, #slctField, #slctAttribute').change(function () {
            //var fieldvalues = fieldValues; 
            var tableSelected = document.getElementById("slctTable").value;
            var fieldSelected = document.getElementById("slctField").value;
            var attributeSelected = document.getElementById("slctAttribute").value;
            $.ajax({
                "url": "php/getData.php",
                "type": "GET",
                "data": {
                    //fieldValues: fieldValues, 
                    tableList: tableSelected,
                    fieldList: fieldSelected,
                    attributeList: attributeSelected
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // mapData(data);
                }
            })
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change code like this

```
function getData(){
       //Variabelen die worden gehaald uit de gekozen dropdown selecties
        $('#slctTable, #slctField, #slctAttribute').change(function ()
        {
            //var fieldvalues = fieldValues; 
            var tableSelected = $("#slctTable :selected").val();
            var fieldSelected = $("#slctField :selected").val();
            var attributeSelected = $("#slctAttribute :selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                "url": "php/getData.php",
                "type": "GET",
                "data": {
                    //fieldValues: fieldValues, 
                    tableSelected: tableSelected,
                    fieldSelected: fieldSelected,
                    attributeSelected: attributeSelected
                },
                success: function(data){
                   // mapData(data);
                }
            })
        });
    };
```